# ActionController::UnknownFormat on AJAX with remote true

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to open a Bootstrap modal trough remote true calls, cause I need to passa some params to modal.

So, I have this code:

index.html

```
...

<%= link_to("<i class='fa fa-upload'></i>".html_safe, {:controller => :blocked_phone_numbers, :action => :show_modal, :blocked_phone_numbers_group_id => blocked_phone_numbers_groups.id}, :class => "btn btn-primary btn-xs", remote: true) %>

...

<div id="modalImportNumbers">
  <%= render partial: 'show_modal' %>
</div>

...
```

blocked_phone_numbers_controller.rb

```
def show_modal   @blocked_phone_numbers_group = BlockedPhoneNumbersGroup.find(params[:blocked_phone_numbers_group_id]) respond_to do |format|
    format.js   end end
```

show_modal.js.erb

```
$('#modalImportNumbers').html("<%= j render partial: 'show_modal' %>");
$('#modalImportar').modal('show');
```

_show_modal.html.erb

```
<div id="modalImportar" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header" style="background-color: #5a4371; color: #fff">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="modalLabel"><%= t(:item_7) %></h4>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12 col-md-offset-0">
          <div class="modal-body">

            <%= form_tag({:action => "import"}, {:multipart => true}) do |form| %>

              ...

            <% end %>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  root 'login#index'

  match ':controller(/:action(/:id))(.:format)', via: [:get, :post]
end
```

The problem is that I keep getting this error:

ActionController::UnknownFormat (ActionController::UnknownFormat):

app/controllers/blocked_phone_numbers_controller.rb:25:in `show_modal'

NameError: uninitialized constant Mime::HTML

I have jQuery import on my application.js, so, I read about in many threads here but I cant figure out what is happening.

Someone could help me understand this error, please?

I'm using Rails 5.1 and Bootstrap 3.7

Thanks!

Comment: Let me know for further guidance.

Answer (score 0):

routes.rb

```
match '/show_modal' => 'blocked_phone_numbers#show_modal', as: 'show_modal', via: [:get, :post]
```

index.html.erb

```
...

<%= link_to show_modal_path(blocked_phone_numbers_group_id: blocked_phone_numbers_groups.id), class: 'btn btn-primary btn-xs', method: :post, :remote => true do%>
  <i class='fa fa-upload'></i%>
<%end%> 

...

<div id="modalImportNumbers">
  <%= render partial: 'show_modal' %>
</div>

...
```